# Update object data with Sqldelight

Tags: android, kotlin, sqldelight

I am trying to figure out how you would write an `Update` query in the `.sq` files where you pass an object and it will update the whole row

I know you can do a normal update statement where you set the columns with the values but is there a way to just pass the data object similar to how I can insert an object like this

```
insert:
INSERT INTO my_table(id, col1,col2,col3) VALUES ?;
```

I was unable to find any documentation in updating a record similarly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the only way to do this would be an `INSERT OR REPLACE` instead of trying it with an update. `UPDATE` only allows setting columns explicitly, theres no automatic object marshaling